# issue in react code for sending data to multer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, multer, mern

I was trying to send image to backend(multer) I checked multiple times the backend code seems correct,is there a issue in my front end code ? POST code snippet

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup',{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({
                    name: data.get('name'),
                    email: data.get('email'),
                    password: data.get('password'),
                    image:data.get('image')
                  })
            });
```

full auth.js code https://pastebin.com/MHdDRtAX

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use `FormData` object.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const body = new FormData();

body.append('image', input.files[0]);
body.append('name', data.get('name'));
body.append('email', data.get('email'));
body.append('password', data.get('password'));
// add more items as needed

const response = await fetch(URL, { method:'POST', body });
```

Comment: the data is already object of FormData `const data = new FormData(event.target);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a content type mismatch. When using multer, you need use `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`.
The basic idea is to use the FormData object.

Example below

```
const data = new FormData(event.target) 
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup',{
                    method:'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    },
                    body: data
                });
```

In network tab you will find form data with key-value
image should be a file(binary)

in multer, example code like below

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
 
var app = express()    
app.post('api/users/signup', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    // req.file is the `image` file
    // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: after using 'multipart/form-data' its showing `internal server error 500` the data is already object of `FormData const data = new FormData(event.target);`

Comment: @Advitya Sharma,   Did you try your backend to see is it working properly without using front end code. Using tools like Postman for sending image to backend?

Comment: Hi, Advitya. When you log data.get('image'). Do you see it is a File object from devtool console or not

Comment: If everything else is fine, I suggest to take a look of console.log(data.get('image')), Or even check your ImageUpload component.